# Getting "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type" error with jersey while uploading an xml file

Tags: java, jersey

Hi I am new in web services.

I want to upload an xml file through jersey but I am "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type" error on a browser.
Jars that i have included are:

1. com.sun.jersey.jersey-core-1.4.0
2. com.sun.jersey.jersey-server-1.4.0
3. javax.ws.rs
4. jersey-bundle-1.7
5. jersey-json-1.4
6. jersey-multipart-1.4
7. jackson-annotations-2.3.2
8. jackson-core-2.3.2
9. jackson-databind-2.3.2
10. jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2
11. jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2
12. jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2
13. jersey-entity-filtering-2.17
14. jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17

Thanks in advance.

Jsp Code is:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources_CSS_JS/Common.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>GenrateView JSP File</title>
</head>
<body>
       <form:form id="FileM" modelAttribute="FileM" action="rest/welcometowebservice/uploadfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div  style="text-align: center;" class="centerXML">
                        <form:label  path="xmlfileName">Select File: </form:label>
                        <form:input  path="xmlfileName"    name="xmlfileName" id="xmlfileName" class="text" type="file"/><br>
                        <form:errors path="xmlfileName"    cssClass = "error" /><br>

                        <input type="submit"  value ="UploadFile On server.!"/>
                </div>  

 <!-- ********* Below code showing error message from controller if any***********..... -->                
                <form:errors path="*" />
                   <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                   <h4 style="font-style: italic; color: red;">${message}</h4>
                   </c:if>  
 <!-- ********* Above code showing error message from controller if any************..... -->                              
      </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code is:

```
@Path("/welcometowebservice")  
public class XmlToHtml_Server {

    // This method is called if HTML and XML is not requested  

    @POST  
    @Path("/uploadfile")  
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("xmlfileName") InputStream uploadedInputStream,  
                               @FormDataParam("xmlfileName") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) 
    {  
            String fileLocation = "D:\\HomeProjectFiles\\HomeUplodedXMLFiles" + fileDetail.getFileName();  
                    //saving file  
            try {  
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
                int read = 0;  
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  
                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
                while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {  
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);  
                }  
                out.flush();  
                out.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
            String output = "File successfully uploaded to : " + fileLocation;  
            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();  
        }  
}
```

Console output is:
ERROR [STDERR] 22 Mar, 2018 4:04:09 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntitySEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data;boundary=------7e218e9170c82 was not foundERROR [STDERR] 22 Mar, 2018 4:04:09 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity

Comment: can you try MultipartFile instead InputStream uploaded. also, change the variable of  xmlfileName for one input

Comment: Tried but did't work.